# How to merge notifications with a common title in pynotify?

Tags: python, notifications, pynotify

How can I tell a pynotify.Notification object to merge with another that has the same title?

Comment: Why do you think you need that information?

Comment: I want to append to the current notification if it is showing and make a new notification if there is currently no notification showing.

Comment: Have you tried calling `set_hint_string('append', '')` on your notifications?

Comment: Should cause notifications from the same program with the same titles to be merged...

Comment: That does exactly what I want, thanks. Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Per discussion:)

Setting the append hint on your notifications (`set_hint_string('append', '')`) tells the notification daemon that it should merge notifications from your app when they have the same titles.